# Why does half my numbers not line up in my radii chart

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, formatting

Program seems to work just fine. It gives a output but from number 6 through number 9 it throws my circumferences out of line. is this a format problem and if so what would I need to do to fix this. Im using python 3.4.

```
def main():

    print ('Radius\tArea\tCircumference')
    print ('-----------------------------')


for Radius in range(1 , 11):
    round (3)

    Area = (Radius)**2*3.14
    Circumference =  (Radius)*2*(3.14)
    a = Radius
    b = Area
    c = Circumference
    d = round(a, 3)
    e = round(b, 3)
    f = round(c, 3)

    print (d, '\t', (e), '\t', (f))
```

This is the outcome I get

```
1    3.14     6.28
2    12.56    12.56
3    28.26    18.84
4    50.24    25.12
5    78.5     31.4
6    113.04             37.68
7    153.86             43.96
8    200.96             50.24
9    254.34             56.52
10   314.0    62.8
```

Comment: what does out of the line mean?

Can you provide us with the output that you are gettin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your output more attractive with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) like so:

```
print ('{:2d}{:10.3f}{:10.3f}'.format(d, (e), (f)))
```

In this case, the format string means:

Print the first value right-aligned in an integer field 2 characters wide.

Print the second value right-aligned in a decimal field 10 characters wide, with 3 places to the right of the decimal point.

Print the third value right-aligned in a decimal field 10 characters wide, with 3 places to the right of the decimal point.

Also note: if you are using `round()` only to affect the printed output, you can skip that step. The string formatter will round the numbers for you, so you can merely print `a,b,c` instead of `d,e,f`:

```
print ('{:2d}{:10.2f}{:10.2f}'.format(a, b, c))
```

Comment: ok that worked but it needs to be only 2 decimal places would I replace the 3f with 2f?

Comment: Consult the links that I provided for complete information, but yes, you change it to `{:10.2f}` to reduce the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: any chance you would know why my two prints under main do not show up

Comment: Yes, but that's another question. Go ahead and post a new question.